# Why inheritance in python require the parent class to inherit object explicitly?

Tags: python, inheritance

Below is two versions of my code:

**Non-working one**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am A "

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am B "

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()

c = C()
```

This raises exception:

```
    super(C, self).__init__()  
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

**Working version**

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
         print "I am A "

class B:
    def __init__(self):
         print "I am B "

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
         super(C, self).__init__()

c = C()
```

If one of the parent class has inherited **object** explicitly , there is no exception and things works as desired. Any explanation, why?

With the above **working one** , it prints "I am A" but not "I am B" which means it initializes only Class A and not Class B. HOw to initialize multiple parent classes in children class?

Comment: [Note: super() only works for new-style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

Comment: If you upgraded to Python 3, I believe this would be a non-issue, too. Maybe check out the according PEP that was implemented in Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[super()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) only works for new-style classes(Any class which inherits from object).So You couldn't pass class object to `super`.

> There are two typical use cases for super. In a class hierarchy with single inheritance, super can be used to refer to parent classes without naming them explicitly, thus making the code more maintainable. This use closely parallels the use of super in other programming languages.

The second use case is to support cooperative multiple inheritance in a dynamic execution environment. This use case is unique to Python and is not found in statically compiled languages or languages that only support single inheritance. This makes it possible to implement “diamond diagrams” where multiple base classes implement the same method. Good design dictates that this method have the same calling signature in every case (because the order of calls is determined at runtime, because that order adapts to changes in the class hierarchy, and because that order can include sibling classes that are unknown prior to runtime).

a typical superclass call looks like this:

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(C, self).method(arg)
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because `super` only works with new-style classes (that inherit from `object`). In Python 2, classes where `object` is nowhere in the inheritance hierarchy (like your first example) are called *old-style* classes, and should never be used anywhere.

It's an old historical artifact from when Python first got OO added to it, and the developers got it wrong. Among other things, new-style classes allow for the use of `super`, the descriptor protocol (properties), and makes several fixes to the way multiple inheritance is handled. `super` is one of them, but the most important is the way method resolution order is computed for diamond inheritance cases (A inherits from B and C which both inherit from D). Read more about it here: http://python-history.blogspot.fr/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Note that Python 3 ditched old-style classes entirely, and thus in Python 3 all classes are new-style classes and inherit from object, regardless of whether or not they do it explicitly.

Comment: OK so now for my python2.7, mine first example will fail but if I move to python 3.x first example will be fine??? SO , in older styled classes , how inheritance works???

Comment: In old-style classes, single inheritance works correctly (the equivalent of super is an explicit call to the superclass, e.g. `ParentClass.my_method(self, arg1, arg2)`), but multiple inheritance fails in surprising and hard to catch ways. Just don't use old-style classes (they're also a bit slower). And yes, in Python 3 your two examples are exactly equivalent.

Comment: With new styled classes , how can one initialize multiple Parent classes at time. In my example how to initialize both class A and class B?

Comment: You need all your classes in your hierarchy to have exactly *one* call to `super(CurrentClass, self).__init__()` in their own `__init__` method. `super` doesn't call the superclass -- it calls *the next class in the method resolution order* (which is the superclass in the single-inheritance case, but not always in complex multiple-inheritance cases).

Comment: U mean to say, that there is no way a child can initialize multiple parents? Or it has to invoke multiple super() ?

Comment: Don't think multiple super() in child will do anything else, instead initializing first parent.

Comment: The `super` calls in the parents pass initialization around to each other. Read the article I linked above about MRO in Python.

Comment: didn't got the way to initialize both, tell me how to print "I am A" and "I am B" both.

Comment: Read the documentation and re-read my comments. Your code is wrong (it's missing `super` calls in `A` and `B`).

Comment: I don't know whether my code is wrong or not b'coz it executes fine and initialize A. But yes, when I put super() in both parent classes I see both gets initialized against only A getting initialized. :)